# How to access an instance of object in ArrayList of type InnerClass from another class?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, singleton

The outer-class is ==> Bank [which is singleton][the method (getTheOneBank())will return the singleton object.

The inner-class is ==> Account [has many instances like : id,moneyAmount,.....]

- class Bank has an arrayList of type Account [private ArrayList accounts]
- class Bank has a method of type arrayList to return (accounts).

How to access the (id) instance of object (Account) that in ArrayList (accounts) ,from another class let us say(the main class).

here is my code:

```
for (Bank.Account obj : Bank.getAccounts()) 
        {
            System.out.println(obj.id);
        }
```

Comment: And what is your problem? What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Bank bank = new Bank();
for (Bank.Account obj : bank.getAccounts()) 
{
    System.out.println(obj.id);
}
```